# Is Laravel introducing new programming syntax?

Tags: laravel, oop, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-middleware

What is this Closure $next. Ok I am guessing an object but how a object reference accepts an argument $request? Shouldn’t it call method. Closure in php are anonymous function but is it that the next is an anonymous function variable defined else where? I see the handle method is in Class Frameguard but the above example didn’t even instantiate Frameguard Class. Am I correct to say Laravel does not follow oop syntax?

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->age <= 200) {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: Laravel middleware implement the [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)) software architecture pattern which is a valid OOP pattern

Comment: Thanks I will look in to it

Answer (score 0):

Now, it does not. Laravel is just framework so it allows you to complete some every-day actions in easier and faster way.

Obviously Laravel follows OOP and there is no something like "OOP syntax" as far as I know. But there are parts in Laravel and every other framework that are not so obvious.

Basically in middleware you have access to Request and closure. You can read about middleware [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware). If you want to dig in dipper you can look at `\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline` class - there is `carry` method in there that is responsible for looping over each used middleware.